# Execute SQL Procedures in Hive

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

​Hi,

Below is the scenario we have, please suggest possible solutions,

We have an existing reporting solution (SAP) executing a procedure in RDBMS (using JDBC Connection) to generate reports based on the user input.

Now we are planning to move from RDBMS to hive as our data source.

Is there a way to connect to hive and execute a procedure (HPLSQL or a UDF performing an equivalent job of Oracle procedure) using a JDBC connection?

Or is there any alternate way to run a procedure or a program in hive or spark using jdbc?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to connect to Hive using JDBC

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-JDBC

However if your cluster is secured, you will need to connect to HiveServer2

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC

Plus to that, store procedures are supported in Hive from the 2.0.0 version

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11055

Comment: Thanks for the response hlagos. Is it possible to trigger a HPL/SQL procedure using jdbc and get a view returned.      Similar to how we trigger a procedure in Oracle which returns a temporary view.

Comment: not sure what do you mean by getting a view returned, but you should be able to get a set of records from the store procedure.